# pull data to a specific sheet within a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a new to Script editor on google spreadsheet and not much of a programmer.
I've been working with google docs for sometime now and it has become an important tool in my daily activity.
What I'm trying to do, is the following:
Seek a whole document (with severall sheet such as "1", "2", "3", and so on, corresponding to the number of days a month can hold) and if the column 7 shows a determined value (in my case, it will be RECEBER), pull all the data in that row and write onto a sheet created for this purpose.
What's happening is that I'm using the the event onEdit to trigger this function. At first sight, it would be ideal, but in my case, I copy a lot of data from other spreadsheets and the paste command does not trigger the onEdit event. Instead, I have to edit the cell manually in order to get that row copied onto the other sheet.
I could run it just once, once tha whole days of the month were filled and there were any changes left to do, but what I really want to do is to make it immediately, as soon as the content is inserted into the spreadsheet.

There's also another problem with my code, it has to be fit and adapted to all the other sheets, as the if clause only performs the full operation if the active sheet equals "1". Anyway, I believe there is a simple solution to this.

Here's the code found on the net that already took me halfway:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "1" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "RECEBER") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("money");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

I'll appreciate all the help you can give.
Thanks in advance.

Diogo Sousa

-- Updated 12Oct --

I've changed the logics on my code, and as patt0 suggested, I run the script from the menu created. I've tried adapting the code, but I believe there's some section wrong. The script runs, but isn't writing anything at all on my target sheet.

here's the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "RECEBER", functionName: "RECEBER"} ];
  ss.addMenu("Scripts", menuEntries);
}

function mustBeCopied(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNumber = parseInt(sheetName);
  if (sheetNumber <=31 && sheetNumber >=1)
    return true;
  return false;
}

function RECEBER() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  if(mustBeCopied(s.getName()) && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "RECEBER") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("money");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

the function Mustbecopied, from what I believe, only sets the range of sheets (1 to 31) eligible;
the function RECEBER will determine if the value on the column 7 will satisfy the condition (RECEBER), so it can retrieve all the row information and move it to the target sheet.

Maybe the trouble is the active sheet thing.. can I us eit in my own advantage and apply the script to the selected sheet?
Also, if I could have both option (whether to apply it to the selected sheet or to the whole document), that wouuld be great and simplify my daily work a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really multiple questions in one, and I will only deal with the second part, the first part has quite a number of dimensions (how to update summary sheets effectively), which we can discuss with another question maybe.

In order to determine if the data in a particular sheet needs to be copied, you could create a simple function that returns a boolean if the sheet satisfies the condition that it is a number between 1 and 31.

```
function mustBeCopied(sheetName) {
  var sheetNumber = parseInt(sheetName);
  if (sheetNumber <=31 && sheetNumber >=1)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Bear in mind that a sheet with the name "28.7" would satisfy the condition.

The first line of your onEdit() script would then look like this

```
if(mustBeCopied(s.getName()) && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "RECEBER")
```

Let me know if this works for you.

--- Oct 14 ---

As far as I can see, the issue that remains, is that when your function was running onEdit, the range (active range) was the cell that was just edited. So the range would be only one cell.

In order for the scrip to run, you would need to highlight each cell to be copied before selecting the menu, which would be tedious to say the least

Further if you have a defined range to be copied, which is the same on each page, we can copy that range every time, or iterate through each row in the column to look for "RECEBER" and get those rows copied.

Further We can try to update your function so that iterate through all the sheets is a many similar to this.

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i::) {
    var s = sheets[i];
    if (mustBeCopied(s.getName()) {
        var range = s.getRange(someRow, 7, someNumOfRows);
        for (var j = 1; j <= someNumOfRows; j++) {
            if (range.getCell(j,1).getValue() == "RECEBER") {
                //YOUR COPY CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how this works.

Comment: I used your code and it's working flawless. Now it can adapt to any sheet range that I want without having to change the code everytime I want to apply it to a new sheet.

I just think that the onEdit event should respond whenever I paste new content onto my document taken from other spreadsheets. As new data is being inserted, it should be interpreted as an effective edit to the sheet. Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you so much for your time and attention.

Comment: Maybe if I could run this script everytime the spreadsheet is opened it would be better. I tried swapping the onEdit with onOpen, but it doesn't seem to run.
Anyway it would be a good idea, as everytime the spreadsheet is opened, the script runs and brings an up-to-date result on the targer sheet.. Any comments on this are welcome..
By the way, am I replying in the appropriated field?

Comment: Unfortunately the copy and past will not trigger the onEdit().  You could have a menu to launch the updates, you would need to provide range information to copy only what need to be updated, and also not copying rows twice (or ensure that you overwrite). So when you open the sheet, the menus are added to it and you can then call the update function : menu tutorial is here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/defining_menus

Comment: That's a very good idea. I've followed the guggested tutorial and already have a script ready to run. The bad thing is that it does nothing. I've been making some changes to the coda that I had previously, but it seems I can't adapt a code designed for the onEdit to a simple running script whenever it is called.. I will try learning how each stage of this script works individually. I hope I'll be able to put something together.. Many thank for your help patt0